# Add add/remove class click picture in queue jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, gallery, addclass

I have those pictures

```
<img src=img1.jpg class=pic />
<img src=img2.jpg class=pic />
<img src=img3.jpg class=pic />
<img src=img4.jpg class=pic />
<img src=img5.jpg class=pic />
<img src=img6.jpg class=pic />

.ShowBorderRed{border:3px solid red;}
```

I want to add the class `.ShowBorderRed` once I click one of them and remove this class once I click another picture and add the class to this new image. `JQuery`

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please consider posting the relevant code too. For this case, you did not include the code that you have tried using with jQuery.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, you should mark an answer so future visitors seeking an answer to the same question can have an indication of which solution worked best for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $img = $('.pic');
    $img.click(function(event){
        $img.removeClass('ShowBorderRed');
        $(this).addClass('ShowBorderRed');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See the comments inline in the code:

```
// bind click event on all the images having pic class
$('img.pic').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('ShowBorderRed') // Add class to the clicked image
        .siblings().removeClass('ShowBorderRed'); // Remove class from other sibling images
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wyrytjb0/)

**OR**

If the images are not `siblings`:

```
var $images = $('img.pic');
$images.on('click', function() {
    $images.removeClass('ShowBorderRed'); // Remove class from all other images
    $(this).addClass('ShowBorderRed'); // Add class to the clicked image
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wyrytjb0/3/)

Comment: I would avoid using `.siblings()`. It is not necessary to make jQuery iterate check the DOM tree when a simple class selector can be used to do the same thing. The 2nd option is the way to go...

Answer (score -1):

```
Use the following code:

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $img = $('.pic');
    $img.click(function(event){
        $img.removeClass('ShowBorderRed');
        $(this).addClass('ShowBorderRed');
    });
});
refer the below mentioned link.
http://jsfiddle.net/2QyY3/199/
```